# HTML Import not working in Chrome Latest Version after using webcomponents

Tags: html-imports, polymer-1.x

I am using polymer in my project. My polymer version is **1.12.0** and webcomponent version is **0.7.24**.  Even I used the webcomponent, I am getting HTML Import error (HTML Imports is deprecated and has now been removed as of M80). Is there any way to resolve this error or it won't works in this version.

Answer (score 0):

Polymer is deprecated, too...

You could try to use the HTML Import polyfill, but it's not sure it will always work.

https://github.com/webcomponents/html-imports